# Update Stored Procedure with a DataBound CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a webapp that dynamically generates images (i.e. Barcodes). The images are generated using user input. The user chooses data from a databound checkbox lists, that data is then concatenated a date using a date picker, and lastly the user enters an amount. That then creates a number of images from the amount entered by the user.

My program runs and generates the images with no issue. I want to eventually have the information entered by the user sent to a database, that way, the amount entered will be sequenced, which resets itself after every 24 hours.

My issue is at the moment, when I run my app, and enter the information, if 1 checkbox is selected, it updates the information with no issue, along with successfully generating the images. If I choose more than one checkbox my database will only update the first checkbox selected in my CheckBoxList and it's respective row in the database.

Here is my C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
           this.CheckBoxListDataBind();
           //Binds Database Data to CheckBoxList1
     }

 }

private string GetConnectionString()
{
     //SQL Connection String
     return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["DatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
}


//method to bind CheckBoxList
public void CheckBoxListDataBind()
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AccountID, AccountName FROM AccountTable ORDER BY AccountID ASC;"
         cmd. Connection = conn;
         conn.Open();

         using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while(sdr.Read())
              {

                ListItem. item = new ListItem();             
                item.Text = sdr["AccountID"].ToString() + "-" + sdr["AccountName].ToString(); 
                item.Value = sdr["AccountID"].ToString();
                item.Text = sdr{"AccountName].ToString();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AccountID", CheckBoxList1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AccountName", CheckBoxList1)
                CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);

             }
         }

         conn.Close();
     }

//method to generate image
public Bitmap DrawBarcode(string data, string label)
{
    Bitmap dyn_image = new Bitmap(date,Length * 27, 150);

    PointF point = new PointF(2,2)

    Font dyn_image_font = new Font("ImageFontName", 16, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);

    Font label_font = new Font("Tahoma", 9, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Reguar, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dyn_image);

    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dyn_image);

    graphics.Clear(Color.White);

    graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, dyn_image.Width, dyn_image.Height);

    graphics.DrawString(dyn_image_font, label_font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), point);

    RectangleF rectF = new RectangleF(5 , 100, 250, 170); 

    graphics.DrawString(label, label_font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), rectF);

    graphics.Flush();

    graphics.Dispose();

    System.Web.UI.Controls.Image gen_image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       dyn_image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

       Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
       gen_image.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

    }

 return dyn_image;

}


//button click method handles user inputs
protected void Generate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyle style = DateTimeStyle.None;
  DateTime dt;
  DateTime.TryParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", provider, style out dt)"
  int i = Int32.Parse(amount.Text);

  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  conn.Open();

  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.CommandText = "Update_Account_Table";

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqNum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue;

      foreach(List item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
      {   
         //this forloops is for the DrawImage() method to generate more than
         //one image from user input amount 
         for(int n = 1; n <= i; n++) 
         {

            if (item.Selected)
            {

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                string barcode_label = item.Text + "QTY:___________"

                //When image generates, it will show 1 to user input amount                 
                string barode_data = item.Value + datepicker.Text + n.ToSTring("D2");

                 Bitmap dynImage = DrawBarcode(barcode_data, barcode_label)

                 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                 dynImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                 byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                 Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

                 img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

                 panel1.Controls.Add(img);

                  double spacing;

                  double mg = 5;

                  spacing = img.Width.Value + mg;

            }

         } 

          //handling parameters in loop.
         cmd.Parameters["@SeqNum"].Value = amount.Text;
         cmd.Parameters["@SeqDate"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         cmd.Parameters["@Account_ID"].CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

       conn.Close();
}
```

SQL Code

```
CREATE TABLE AccountTable
(
    RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
    AccountID varchar(2),
    AccountName varchar(50),
    SeqNum int,
    SeqDate datetime
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [ACCOUNTTABLE_UPDATE]
(
  @SeqNum int,
  @SeqDate datetime,
  @Account_ID varchar(2)
)

AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
UPDATE AccountTable
SET SeqNum = @SeqNum, SeqDate = @SeqDate
WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
END
```

On my webpage I have a checkboxlist, a textbox that reads an int value, another textbox that uses a JQuery Calender for input, as well as a javascript print function that prints the panel from a webpage and finally, the CheckBoxList uses another javascript function to check all the boxes or uncheck them.

As stated before, my code works fine, but it's not updating the database as intended. It will only update one row in the database which is determined by the Account_ID selected in the checkboxlist. As long as 1 is selected, any selection can be update. If I select all in the checkboxlist, or more than one, only the first checkbox in the list is updated.

Comment: what if you add an explicit `Commit` to your stored procedure..? what if you run the update manually in sql server enterprise manager.. does it update the table correctly..?

Comment: I tried the commit and it didn't seem to help, but yes I can update using the sp with no issue

Comment: then there is obviously something you are doing wrong in your code.. I will take a closer look at your code later this afternoon to see if I can spot something..

Comment: you should also wrap this around a `try{}catch(SqlException ex){}`
`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: wrap it around the loop in the method, I'll try that and see, thank you.

Comment: when ever you execute anything it's always best to not assume that the code won't error thus wrapping it around and or doing error trapping and handling is always best this way you can report on the error message in your case it would be `try{}catch(SqlException ex){MessaageBox.Show(ex.Message)}`

Comment: which makes sense since I did have a try and catch before, but not around the method, thus when executing the code, it yielded the same results.

Comment: you don't need it around the method you need it around the portion of the code where you are calling the following  `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` since this is a web app you will show a message using either JavaScript or you can write out the response.. if you are not familiar with the JavaScript `Alert` google can help you with finding tons of examples here on Stackoverflow

Comment: I'm sorry I meant around that, I apologize the for error.

Comment: I implemented the try and catch which is not throwing any errors, but instead updates all records in the table despite only one record selected, For example, if the first checkbox is selected, all records are updated, if the second is selected, all of them are updated except for the **first** one. I figured it was a problem with that this entire time.

Comment: when you need to add an additional WHERE clause.. you need to understand the basics in regards to SQL UPDATES.. look at your data and figure out what's unique about it .. for example if you have a unique ID then capture that and update that field based on the selection otherwise what you are getting is expected behavior...